# Deklination von "(Schoko-)Raspel(n)" und "(Hornhaut-)Raspeln"

Tags: regional, declension

Das Wort *Raspel* gibt es mit zwei Grundbedeutungen:

- geraspelte Stückchen, oftmals von Nahrungsmitteln wie Schokolade, Gemüse o. ä.
  **Beispiel:** Schokoraspel
- ein Gerät zum Zerkleinern oder Hobeln (beispielsweise grobe Feile, Küchenreibe)
  **Beispiel:** Hornhautraspel

Laut Duden ist das Wort in der [ersten Bedeutung ein Maskulinum](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Raspel_Stueckchen_Teil) mit dem Plural *Raspel* und in der [zweiten Bedeutung ein Femininum](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Raspel_Kuechengeraet_Feile) mit dem Plural *Raspeln*.

Das heißt also, kleine Schokostückchen heißen *Schokoraspel* und nicht *Schokoraspeln*. Leider deckt sich dies nicht mit meiner Erfahrung und Intuition: Ich kenne das Wort im Plural als *Schokoraspeln*, mit einem *-n* (im Singular würde ich das Wort hingegen gar nicht verwenden und könnte auch kein Geschlecht angeben).

Google ich nach den beiden Begriffen, erhalte ich folgende Ergebnisse:

- ***Schokoraspeln:*** 94.000 Treffer
- ***Schokoraspeln -Schokoraspel:*** 76.300 Treffer
- ***"die Schokoraspeln":*** 2.620 Treffer
- ***Schokoraspel:*** 120.000 Treffer
- ***Schokoraspel -Schokoraspeln:*** 37.600 Treffer
- ***"die Schokoraspel":*** 2.660 Treffer

Ein Vergleich zwischen den Suchbegriffen *Schokoraspel* und *Schokoraspeln* bestätigt zwar die Dudenangabe, dass es in dieser Bedeutung *Raspel* heißt. Die Differenz ist aber recht klein. Natürlich kann dies auch an einer Dativ-Plural-Verunreinigung liegen, die bei beiden Wörtern *den Raspeln* lautet. Deshalb habe ich nochmal nach der Variante mit Nominativ/Akkusativ-Artikel *die* gegoogelt, wo der Unterschied aber recht gering ausfällt. Da es aber nur jeweils etwa 2.600 Treffer gibt, traue ich mich nicht, daraus eine allgemeine Aussage zu folgern.

***Meine Frage:***
Kann man die Aussage so pauschal treffen, dass *die Raspeln* im Sinne von *die geraspelten Stückchen* falsch ist? Handelt es sich vielleicht um einen Regionalismus, wenn *Raspeln* als Plural beider Bedeutungen verwendet wird?

Comment: Was mir beim googeln dazu noch auffällt ist dass Google mich wenn ich nach `schokoraspeln` suche nett fragt ob ich vielleicht `schoko raspeln` meine, was für mich normalerweise ein Anzeichen ist, dass es meinen Suchbegriff nicht gibt oder er ungewöhnlich ist. Andererseits wusste ich bis eben nicht einmal, dass der schokoraspel ein maskulinum ist und kann mich nicht erinnern jemals `schokoraspel` als plural gehört zu haben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zwei Probleme, die hierbei wohl zu berücksichtigen sind:

a) Erfahrung und Intutition sind nicht immer die verlässlichsten Ratgeber;

b) Google ist nicht unbedingt das ideale Recherchetool für diese spezielle Art von Frage.

Zu b:
Wenn ich mir überlege, in welchen Kontexten die beiden Begriffe wohl überwiegend auftauchen werden, komme ich auf Seiten, wo man die Dinger kaufen kann (sprachlich oft nicht sonderlich ausgefeilt, besonders bei preiswerten Produkten). Und dann komme ich vor allem auf Rezeptseiten, Koch-Foren u.ä. Auch hier wäre ich vorsichtig, den Sprachgebrauch als vorbildlich zu bezeichen - auch wenn er wohl als repräsentativ angesehen werden kann.
Und das bringt uns auch gleich wieder zurück zu a): Die wenigsten achten in Koch-Foren darauf, ob es konkret der oder die Raspel heißt - das wird ja in der Regel aus dem Kontext ersichtlich: einmal soll ein Teelöffel davon über die Nachspeise gestreut werden, ein anderes Mal soll man die Schokolade damit reiben. Grammatik und Orthografie sind hier nicht Priorität.

Fazit: Wenn man es sicher richtig machen will, nach dem Duden richten.

Edit: Und vielleicht dann doch noch zur gestellten Frage... sorry!

Wenn man den Duden u.ä. als Standard nimmt, kann man tatsächlich pauschal sagen, dass die beiden verschiedenen Wörter verschiedene Bedeutungen haben - und somit auch nicht der Plural des einen Wortes willkürlich die Bedeutung des anderen übernehmen kann.
Dass diese Verwaschung aber gängige Praxis ist, dafür können die Google-Ergebnisse nun tatsächlich als Beleg dienen :)

(P.S.:Ich habe Zweifel, dass es sich beim konkreten Fall um einen Regionalismus handelt, kann das aber nicht belegen.)

Comment: Ein drittes Problem muss berücksichtigt werden: Der Duden gibt nicht vor was wir als richtig oder falsch zu bewerten haben (Ursache = Duden; Wirkung = richtig/falsch). Es ist genau anders rum: Der Duden beschreibt, was die meisten Sprecher (und Schreiber) verwenden (Ursache = Sprachgebrauch, Wirkung = Duden). Wenn man so schreiben (und sprechen) will wie es die große Masse tut, hilft ein Blick in den Duden. Dieser Wunsch steht aber nicht hinter jeder Text-Produktion, daher sind Abweichungen durchaus zulässig, ohne dass man ihnen gleich den Stempel »Fehler« aufdrücken muss.